# How do I make an array that randomly chooses an event, is it possible? (re-creating google I'm feeling lucky button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am re-making the google I'm feeling lucky animation and I'm just wondering how I can display one of these events on my button but make it so it randomly chooses its height. They way it works is that I have a button with a max height and I hid the overflow. The html and css are fine, I just want the jQuery to randomly select one of those elements.

```js
$('.mainbutton:nth-child(2)').hover(function() { //jQuery
  var list = $(".mainbutton ul").toArray();
  var elemlength = list.length;
  var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * elemlength);
  var randomitem = list[randomnum];

  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-170px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-130px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-100px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-70px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-40px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-10px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-180px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-220px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-250px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-170px');
  $('.' + randomitem).css('bottom', '-170px');
});
```

```css
.mainbutton {
  padding: 0px 0px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 29 6px;
  color: #757575;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 34px;
  width: 144px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.mainbutton:nth-child(1) {
  bottom: 13px;
}
.mainbutton ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.mainbutton ul {
  padding-left: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -160px;
  width: 144px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-buttons" align="center">
  <button class="mainbutton">Google Search</button>
  <button class="mainbutton">
    <ul>
      <li>I'm Feeling Stellar</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Artistic</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Wonderful</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Curious</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Hungry</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Lucky</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Doodley</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Generous</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Trendy</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Puzzled</li>
      <li>I'm Feeling Playful</li>
    </ul>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array already holds a list of DOM elements, and you have already randomly selected it into the variable `randomitem`.

Re-selecting them via `$('.'+ randomitem )` will not work because `randomitem` is a DOM element, not a string.

A `.something` selector would select elements with class `something`.

In your case, you would want to select the item via something like:

```
//Pass DOM element directly into JQuery to get a JQuery object with the appropriate element selected
var $randomitem = $(list[randomnum]);

//Set css to whatever you want.
$randomitem.css('bottom', '-170px');

//Subsequent css updates
```

Finally, your animation will not work like you would expect because there is no delay between changing the css of the elements. You would see the css update to the last value, and no values in between.

You ideally want to add a delay between successive css updates in order to see each individual step.

Comment: Do you know how I could apply those delays between the css updates?

Comment: @Alex look into the JQuery [`.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function. You can use it to chain a series of css updates with delays in between.

For example, something like: `$randomitem.css('bottom', '-170px').delay(500).css('bottom', '-200px').delay(600).css('bottom', '-100px').delay(700)`